# error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator>' if(min > max)

Tags: c++

I am getting this error while compiling this program. This questions is to find max of min's window size. Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {

            int n;
            cin>>n;
            int a[n];
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                cin>>a[i];//to take input as array
            }
            for(int k=1; k<=n; k++)
            {
                int max=0;
                for(int i=0; i<n-k; i++)
                {
                    int min=a[i];
                    for(int j=0; j<k; j++)
                    {
                        if(a[i+j]<min)
                        {
                            min=a[i+j];
                        }
                    }
                }
               if(min > max)
               {
                   max=min;
               }
                cout<<max<<" ";
            }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), though some compilers add it as a non-standard and non-portable extension. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: As for your error, please edit your question to include the *full* and *complete* copy-pasted (as text) error output, including any possible informational notes. Put it in the body of the question. And please show *where* in your code the error is, for example by adding a comment on that line.

Comment: Remove `using namespace std;`.

Comment: And a small hint about the problem: [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) and [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min)... And read [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I am getting this error
Compilation Error:
Compilation Error
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:31:18: error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator>'
         if(min > max)
                  ^
prog.cpp:33:16: error: cannot resolve overloaded function 'min' based on conversion to type 'int'
             max=min;
                ^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are hiding (shadowing) the `std::min` and `std::max` functions by the local declarations of `int max` and `int min`. However, this shadowing only happens in the local scope, where these variables are declared.

When you leave the scope, the outer name becomes visible again:

```
        int max=0;                  // <-- Here max hides std::max
        for(int i=0; i<n-k; i++)
        {
            int min=a[i];          // <-- Here min hides std::min
            for(int j=0; j<k; j++)
            {
                if(a[i+j]<min)
                {
                    min=a[i+j];
                }
            }
        }                       // <-- But here the local min goes away again

       if(min > max)            // <-- And here min is std::min, a function
```

So the compiler believes that `min > max` is to compare an `int` to a function template. And it cannot see how to do that.

This is one of the reasons why using `using namespace std;` is considered not a good idea.